# |ax+by| less than or equal to $|a+b|?$

Tags: complex-numbers

For a,b,x,y complex with x,y having modulus less than or equal 1 is it possible to show $|ax+by|$ less than or equal to $|a+b|?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take $a=x=1$ and $b=y=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

$|ax+by|\leq |ax|+|by|\leq |a|+|b|$

You can't really get to $\leq |a+b|$ as shown in the example above